# Replacing nested quotes in a faulty string inside XML Attribute using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, html, xml, regex

I have a faulty String inside a XML file: **summary="The name is "Rambo"."**

I would like to replace the inner quotes with `&quot;` using regex so the output would look like:

**summary="The name is `&quot`Rambo`&quot`."**

Comment: What tells you they're *inner* quotes (instead of having two consecutive pairs of quotes)?

Comment: It looks much like the outer quotes were string delimiters actually. Do you have `"The name is \"Rambo\"."` or really `'"The name is "Rambo"."'`?

Comment: I have an XML file with faulty syntax. The strings have the quotes inside the text eg. **summary="Great work by "THE" painter."**. So I need to replace these with `&quot` so that the syntax is correct. After replacement the text should be **summary="Great work by `&quot`THE `&quot` painter."**

Comment: So you have those somewhere in a big string and you don't know where (which below answers assume)?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, buddie!

```js
var outer = '"The name is "Rambo"."';
var inner = outer.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
var final = '"' + inner.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"';
// (string) => "The name is &quot;Rambo&quot;."
```

---

**Edit:** You could shortcut this a little bit, but it's asymmetrical because JavaScript does not support regexp lookbehind

```js
var str = '"The name is "Rambo"."';
var final = '"' + str.substr(1).replace(/"(?!$)/g, '&quot;');
// (string) => "The name is &quot;Rambo&quot;."
```

---

**Edit 2:** Using `str.slice` it looks like this can be even simpler!

```js
var str = '"The name is "Rambo"."';
var final = '"' + str.slice(1, -1).replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"';
// (string) => "The name is &quot;Rambo&quot;."
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly but my problem is regarding XML files. I have an XML file with faulty syntax. The strings in attributes have the quotes inside the text eg. **summary="Great work by "THE" painter."**. So I need to replace these with `&quot` so that the syntax is corrected. After replacement the text should be **summary="Great work by `&quot`THE `&quot` painter."**

Comment: Well that's not the question you posted. If you need to parse XML, you need an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = '"The name is "Rambo"."';
if(str.charAt(0)=='"' && str.charAt(str.length-1)=='"'){
    str = '"'+str.substr(1,str.length-2).replace(/"/g,"&quot;")+'"';
}
console.log(str);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was initially trying to play with `str.substr(1, str.length-2)` but it just feeling kind of ugly

Comment: yeah, thats what made the throw the `if` statement in, just to be sure the first and last characters were double quotes.

Comment: You also could use the more simple `str.slice(1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative regex/`replace` solution

Javascript

```
function innerToQuot(text) {
    var last = text.length - 1;

    return text.replace(/"/g, function (character, position) {
        return (position === 0 || position === last) ? character : "&quot;";
    });
}

console.log(innerToQuot('"The name is "Rambo"."'));
```

Output

```
"The name is &quot;Rambo&quot;."
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/tSYJM/)</kbd>

**Update:** Based on your updated question.

Parse the XML to obtain your string value, then.

```
function innerToQuot(text) {
    var match = text.match(/^([^"]*)(\s*=\s*)([\s\S]*)$/),
        result = "",
        first = 0,
        last = -1;

    if (match) {
        result += match[1] + match[2];
        text = match[3];
        last += text.length;
    } else {
        first = last;
    }

    return result + text.replace(/"/g, function (character, position) {
        return (position === first || position === last) ? character : "&quot;";
    });
}

var text = 'summary="The name is "Rambo"."',
    newText = innerToQuot(text);

console.log(newText);
```

Output

```
summary="The name is &quot;Rambo&quot;."
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EbzsA/)</kbd>

Write the new string back to the XML

Answer (score 0):

This script should fix all wrong quotes inside attributes:

```js
var faultyXML = '<example summary="The name is "Rambo"."/>',
    xmlString = faultyXML.replace(
        /([^"=<>\s]+)="(.+?)"(?=\s+[^"=<>\s]+="|\s*\/?>)/g,
        function(match, name, value) {
            return name+'"'+value.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")+'"';
        }
    );
```

The regex looks complicated but is not :-)

```
([^"=<>\s]+)     # group matching the attribute name. Simpler: (\w+)
="               # begin of value
(.+?)            # least number of any chars before…
"(?=             # a quote followed by
 \s+[^"=<>\s]+=" # whitespace, attribute name, equals sign and quote
 |               # or
 \s*\/?>         # the tag end
)
```